# Textbox With 2 Classes?

Tags: html, class, textbox

Is it possible to have a HTML textbox with two classes attached to it?

```
<input type="text" name="inputxt" class="class1" class="class2">
```

So that you can apply apply two different jQuery scripts to run "on" the one textbox.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="inputxt" class="class1 class2" />`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add 2 different class by this

```
<input type="text" name="inputxt" class="class1 class2">
```

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down - I couldn't find the answer.  Thanks for this - I never realised you could add two classes separated by a space.

Answer (score 2):

Could be `<input type="text" name="inputxt" class="class1 class2">`